# Validating International Telephone Input using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, intl-tel-input

Geeks!

We all know that awesome plugin called International Telephone Input,is there a way to tie it's own Validation method `intlTelInput("isValidNumber")` into jquery validation ?

> `intlTelInput("isValidNumber")`  returns **true** if true or **false** if false

There is more details yet to come below!:

```
var handleContactFormValidation = function () {

    var value_form = $('#contact_form');//form i would like to validate where phone field is in!
    var value_error = $('.alert-danger', value_form);
    var value_success = $('.alert-success', value_form);
    value_form.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "", // validate all fields including form hidden input
        rules: {                             
            phone: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                            if ($(this).intlTelInput("isValidNumber") == true)
                            return true
                        else
                            return false
                    }
                }
            },

        },
```

Now depending on the results "isValidNumber" method is returning i need to pass that validating Output {true,false} to the jquery validation but above is not functioning

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This validation logic makes no sense...

```
rules: {                             
    phone: {
        required: {
            depends: function () {
                if ($(this).intlTelInput("isValidNumber") == true)
                    return true
                else
                    return false
            }
        }
    },
},
```

The way you've written it, the `depends` property is saying that the `phone` field is `required` when the telephone number is valid and the field is not `required` when the telephone number is invalid.  To make this determination, the field has to be filled out. But if the field is already filled out, then the `required` rule no longer matters.  So when it's simply left blank (no valid phone number), it's not `required` and nothing will be validated.

If you want to validate the phone number with the International Telephone Input plugin, then you'll need to [write a custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) that calls this external `.intlTelInput()` method.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    .....
    rules: {                             
        phone: {
            required: true,      // field is mandatory
            intlTelNumber: true  // must contain a valid phone number
        },
    },
    ....
});

// create a custom phone number rule called 'intlTelNumber'
jQuery.validator.addMethod("intlTelNumber", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || $(element).intlTelInput("isValidNumber");
}, "Please enter a valid International Phone Number");
```

---

To do this without using the International Telephone Input plugin...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("intlTelNumber", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace( /\s+/g, "" );
return this.optional( element ) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
    phone_number.match( /^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9])\)|[2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9]))-?[2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9])-?\d{4}$/ );
}, "Please enter a valid International Phone Number");
```

This example shows the regex for a US phone number. Modify it to suit your specific phone number requirements. Hint: look inside your International Telephone Input plugin for the correct regex.

Comment: thank you so much for such scientific answer  ,I always respect experts with solid theory background (not try and trail).

Comment: there is a problem for phone field that it's actually an array of inputs( phone[ ] ) which may affect jquery validation since  jquery validation can deal with only one field for each rule ,thus i decided to make a manual validation away from jq validation by adding class errors and spans manually the problem is how to block the form to submit if the validated field form-group has error ?

Comment: @SuhaybKharabsheh, I fully answered your question about the jQuery Validate plugin.  If you decided to take another approach and encounter a new problem, then please post it as a new question.

Comment: @NarenVerma, ok thanks.  I fixed the answer.  `phone_number` should have been the name of the value argument going into the function.  Copied from the plugin's additional methods file.